# ASp.NET MVC/WebApi Hosting multiple areas independently

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

You have a single asp.net webapi project with different areas.

The question is is it possible to host one of them over the Internet and make it accessible for web users  while keeping the other(s) accessible only for the local network users?

I know it's not possible to assign areas different pools and nothing comes to mind on how to configure IIS to limit the users of any of the areas to the local network.

One possible solution is for sure just taking the local areas out of the main project and hosting them under dedicated app pools and IIS apps. And the second way to do this is to perform fine-grained security and simply restrict the access of the users based on the custom authentication attributes.

But I hope it should really be possible to deny access to the website based on some directory/path/pattern filtering.
Any ideas guys?

Comment: It's a bad idea to have information on a public facing server when that server contains information that should not be accessed by the public. If they managed to break in (through the public site) they could have access to data contained in the private site. Ideally, a public facing server should be locked down extremely tight, on its own VLAN etc. With that said, you can simply host your site on different ports, and configure the firewall to have the port open that leads to the public site.

Comment: What about blocking a controller by IP or HostAdress or your local network?

Comment: @msm8bball, your right about the security hole. but then if you host the same app with the same areas on two ports and open one of them then the Internet users will be able request for the end-points of the are I want to keep for the local requests only right?

Comment: @DmitryKvochkin is it possible to identify in ASp.NET whether the http request is from the local network or not? That would be more convenient...need to search for that, but thanks for the hint ;)

Comment: If your local network have static IP, just use it as global variable or store in db.

Comment: OK, but this solution is not secure for the production code because it's possible to spoof the IP from the client...general rule-of-thumb don't trust clients :)
There's either a solution at configuration level such as IIS/firewall or there's no reliable solution for this.

Comment: Arman, I don't understand your last question directed at me. You're basically repeating what I'm saying. You have one port intended for Internet traffic, that port will be allowed through the firewall. You keep the other port for local traffic, and the firewall blocks access to it.

Comment: @msm8bball, yea, I see it. The app has say two areas, if you host the whole app on a port then both areas will be accessible. I was looking for a way to somehow restrict access to a part of a web app without any coding, maybe based on some routing. I hope this makes it clear.